# Overriding Equals and type casting

Tags: c#, polymorphism, equality, unary-operator

In this following example the third evaluation returns false, all good, but the fourth example returns true..
I don't quite understand how this works however, by default `Object.Equals` compares two references for object equality, and seeing as `a` and `b` both point to a unique instance of a string, this should return false, which it does in the third example but not in the fourth.
Now I understand why it returns true in the 2nd example seeing as the `.Equals()` method is overridden in the string class, but in the fourth example we're casting this string as an object.
So wouldn't it call `Object.Equals` in this case?

```
static void Main()
{
    // Create two equal but distinct strings
    string a = new string(new char[] {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'});
    string b = new string(new char[] {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'});

    Console.WriteLine (a == b); // Returns true
    Console.WriteLine (a.Equals(b)); // Returns true

    // Now let's see what happens with the same tests but
    // with variables of type object
    object c = a;
    object d = b;

    Console.WriteLine (c == d); // Returns false
    Console.WriteLine (c.Equals(d)); // Returns true
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The clue is the words "by default". `string` overrides `object.Equals` with a custom implementation. Since `object.Equals` is a polymorphic method (`virtual` / `override` / etc), the most-derived implementation gets used even if the variable (/expression) type is `object`.

`==`, however, is **not** polymorphic; the implementation used depends entirely on the variable (/expression) type. In this case, since the known type is `object`, the only comparison available is reference equality.

Perhaps more succinctly:

```
class Foo {
    public override string ToString() { return "hi"; }
}
//...
object obj = new Foo();
string s = obj.ToString(); // this is "hi"
```

This is the same principle: the most derived overload of a virtual method is used, regardless of the type that the compiler knows about (`object` in this case).

Comment: Right, so even if we cast the string to an object it will still call the overridden implementation of `.Equals` ?

Comment: @OverlyExcessive yes; that is the key point of polymorphism; emphasis: operators such as `==` are **not** polymorphic

Answer (score 1):

The `Equals` method is virtual, that means that even if it is called on an reference with the `object` type, it will end up invoking the implementation for the concrete type of the instance.

From the generated IL: `a.Equals(b)` becomes

```
IL_003C:  ldloc.0     // a
IL_003D:  ldloc.1     // b
IL_003E:  callvirt    System.String.Equals
```

and `c.Equals(d)` becomes

```
IL_0057:  ldloc.2     // c
IL_0058:  ldloc.3     // d
IL_0059:  callvirt    System.Object.Equals
```

So, both are virtual calls on a reference of type string and object, respectively, and both invoke the `Equals` method, not on the reference, but on the instance itself.

On the other hand, `a==b` becomes a call of the static method `System.String.op_Equality`

```
IL_002F:  ldloc.0     // a
IL_0030:  ldloc.1     // b
IL_0031:  call        System.String.op_Equality
```

while `c==d` becomes just

```
IL_004D:  ldloc.2     // c
IL_004E:  ldloc.3     // d
IL_004F:  ceq
```

, a call to the `check-equal` IL instruction, that does just simple reference checking.

---

You can also verify that the overriden implementation is called with code like:

```
class MyClass
{
  public override bool Equals(object obj)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("My Class Equals is called");
      return true;
  }
}

void Main()
{
   object a = new MyClass();
   object b = new MyClass();
   Console.WriteLine (a.Equals(b));
}
```

This will output

```
My Class Equals is called
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Equals is a virtual method, any class that implements equals will automatically override the original equals no matter what. If you want to use the object.Equals, you have to use `object.ReferenceEquals(a,b)`.

For more info look into how virtual methods work, and if you're feeling up to it, how vtables are actually implemented (which is actually quite easy once you get the hang of it)